# How to get double touch position in android?

Tags: android, touch, double

I need to get the positions of each touch when a double touch has done
I know that you can get the position of one touch with:

```
int x = (int)event.getX();
int y = (int)event.getY();
```

how can I get a second x and y?

Answer (score 6):

event.getPointerCount() will tell you how many touch points there are.
To get the other ones, just use an index value in the "Get" method:

x0 = event.getX(0);
 x1 = event.getX(1);
 ...

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a logic inside an onTouch function. Use static variable and keep a count if cout becomes two, it's a double click.