# Detect multiple fingers on screen

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get double touch position in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681582/how-to-get-double-touch-position-in-android)

I am developing an app witch uses mapview.I want to place pinpoint after one second when the user clicks and holds on the screen (long press).My problem is that the pin is pressed if the user makes a zoom action(if they hold the button on the screen long enogh).
How can i detect if the second finger touched the screen while the first one is still pressing?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681582/how-to-get-double-touch-position-in-android/8681779#8681779

Answer (score 0):

Try handling the onTouch event. The second parameter is of type MotionEvent, which will allow you to call getPointerCount () and get the number of touches.